# Let $S =\{e^x, e^{2x}, e^{3x}\}$. Prove that $S$ is a basis for the span of $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

I'm just a little confused on what exactly I'm proving... So far I've proved that its linearly independent, and I'm guessing that by showing that it spans $S$ that it is a basis for $S$.

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

Comment: its enough to show they are linearly independent

Comment: That was it.  A linearly independent set is always a basis for its span.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of span, $S$ spans $\operatorname{Span}(S)$.

Hence by proving that $S$ is linearly independent, you have shown that $S$ is a basis.

Answer (score 1):

It is true:  $S$ is a basis for $\text{span}(S)$ if and only if $S$ is a linearly independent set.

Another way to see that $S$ is linearly independent is to observe that if

$ae^{3x} + be^{2x} + ce^x = 0, \tag 1$

for some $a$, $b$, $c$, not all zero, then

$ae^{2x} + be^x + c = 0, \tag 2$

since

$e^x \ne 0; \tag 3$

we note that both $a$ and $b$ cannot be $0$, lest in accord with (2) $c = 0$ as well, in contradiction to our hypothesis on $a$, $b$, $c$.

Now (2) is a quadratic equation in $e^x$; but this implies $e^x$ may take at most two values, these being the roots of

$ay^2 + by + c = 0; \tag 4$

however, it is manifestly evident that $e^x$, being continuous, takes on an uncountable infinity of values, and thus cannot obey (4); thus the elements of $S$ are linearly independent, and so it is a basis for $\text{span}(S)$.